# Create a wrapper for Serilog

Tags: c#, casting, serilog

I'm using Serilog. To avoid configuration in each microservice I create a private NuGet package with extension like

```
namespace DFX.Logging
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IWebHostBuilder UseLogging(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder) =>
            webHostBuilder.UseSerilog((context, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                var logLevel = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Serilog:MinimumLevel");
                if (!Enum.TryParse<LogEventLevel>(logLevel, true, out var level))
                {
                    level = LogEventLevel.Information;
                }

                loggerConfiguration.Enrich
                    .FromLogContext()
                    .MinimumLevel.Is(level);

                loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                    .WriteTo.Console(
                        theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code,
                        outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}");
            });
    }
}
```

in controller (or somewhere else) I create logger

```
private readonly ILogger _logger = Log.ForContext<Application>();
```

for that I need to add using `using Serilog;`. I want to avoid it and use only my namespace `using DFX.Logging;`. How can I rich that? What I have tried so far:

```
namespace DFX.Logging
{
    // custom wrapper
    public static class Log
    {
        public static ILogger ForContext<TSource>()
        {
            return (ILogger)Serilog.Log.ForContext<TSource>();
        }
    }

    public interface ILogger : Serilog.ILogger
    {
    }
}
```

Then the code compile successfully but at the runtime I got

> 'Unable to cast object of type 'Serilog.Core.Logger' to type
>   'DFX.Logging.ILogger'.'

I realize that I can't cast `Serilog.Core.Logger` to my logger because `Serilog.Core.Logger`  not implement `DFX.Logging.ILogger`, but how it can be implemented?

Comment: Why not just inject ILogger<ControllerClass> in a constructor using [built-in DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and get rid of any reference to Serilog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: **You can't**. At least not as easily as how you are thinking.

If you really want to go this route, some options could be:

- Create your own static `LoggerProxy` class that implements your `ILogger` interface, and wraps an instance of Serilog's `ILogger` by ... writing the C# code
- Create a dynamic `LoggerProxy` (a.k.a. `LoggerInterceptor`) class that gets generated during runtime, using something like [Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) or [LinFu.DynamicProxy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20884/Introducing-the-LinFu-Framework-Part-I-LinFu-Dynam)
- Modify Serilog's code to implement your interface, and recompile it
- Modify Serilog's assembly via .NET IL Weaving, for example, using a [Fody](https://github.com/Fody) extension, to implement your interface

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to depend on your own log proxy, you could use the dot net logging extension for which there is a serilog implementation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger 
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging