# Simple Wrapper for Logging in .Net

Tags: logging, nlog, serilog

I am looking for Simple wrapper for logging in .Net which writes log using frameworks like Serilog, NLog.
I found several posts with answers for logging wrapper. But i am looking for simple working solution with Adapter. I know @Steven provided few code snippets for building custom wrapper. I need full working example of same. Because I have less experience in coding. Please help.

Comment: If you're looking to write your own wrapper, you might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55755495/211672

Comment: This is old but works - https://github.com/ef-labs/slf4net

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to use a wrapper on top of either [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) given that these logging libraries already provide the feature that you are looking for: `Adapter`. i.e. **They can be the wrappers themselves**...

You could pick the logging library that you prefer, and have that logging library output/adapt to anything you need...

- Serilog has [custom "sinks"](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink) and allows you to use Serilog and output to anything, including NLog (in addition to Serilog)
- NLog has [custom "targets"](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target) and allows you to use NLog and output to anything, including Serilog (in addition to NLog)

There are already many [Serilog sinks](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=serilog%20sink) and [NLog targets](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=nlog%20target) available and built by the community, which you can plug into either of these logging libraries.

---

That said, Microsoft recently introduced [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) which is becoming the standard interface for logging in .NET apps, and you could use that as your "wrapper" and plug Serilog or NLog into it. *I personally prefer the other way around (I use Serilog, and plug Microsoft.Extensions.Logging into Serilog), so instead of depending on Microsoft's `ILogger<T>` I depend on Serilog's `ILogger`*.

[LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog) could be another option and was built with that goal of being a generic abstraction that you can plug into logging libraries, but it is a library that had its day and is becoming less relevant now that Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is out and [even the author of LibLog can see that](https://twitter.com/randompunter/status/1194012812907044864).